# How to enlarge an image when viewed on phone?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive site, but one image (animated gif) looks too small on the phone screen. How can I enlarge it on the phone but not on the desktop?

I've tried a media query to enlarge that element to 120%. Didn't work.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="#Ecosys" class="row ecoBG">
    <div class="col-lg-12 ecoBG"><img src="img/ourecosystem.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Our Ecosystem"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media(max-width:500px) {
    h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
} 
    h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.faceBookText {
    font-family: "Arial Black"; font-size: 20px
}
    #Ecosys {
background-size: 120%
}
}
```

I just inherited this and don't know how to implement. The gif needs to be as wide as possible on the phone. The gif on the phone display is expanded pretty much to its borders but the owner wants it to appear larger.

I was hoping to either:
A) Expand the image to 120% or
B) Replace the image with a cropped version.

Clearly I'm in it over my head (as a rank beginner) so a little guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: tried [background-size: 120% 120%;] ?

Comment: Can you provide any working snippet that we can help you.

Comment: Hi you are increasing the div only not the image so please change the `css` to following under media 

`#Ecosys img{
   width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

background-size is a style that can only be applied to background images. You are using the img tag and including the image in the src, so, therefore, that image is not a background image.

Try this fiddle out and let me know if this helps:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.faceBookText {
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-size: 20px;
}

#Ecosys {
  width: 200px;
}

#Ecosys img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="Ecosys" class="row ecoBG">
    <div class="col-lg-12 ecoBG"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/Wq6DnHvHchrTG/giphy.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Our Ecosystem"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, guys, I've tried all the suggestions, but no luck. Tell me, is there a way to actually substitute the image for another one? If so, I can use the cropped image that should grow to take up the space. In other words, the large size gif has a 200px (estimated) border with the important information within that border. I have a version of the gif where I cropped out the border. Can I get the media query to replace the large gif with the cropped one?

Comment: Is there a way to post the image here? I'm sorry for my lack of experience.